# Notification is sent whenever the app is open in Android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I have an app that sends a `notification` with `AlarmManager` **every day at an exact time**.

But it has a bug. **The notification is sent whenever the app is open**.

How can I get to the notification is send once a day? Thank you

**MAINACTIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int d = Integer.valueOf(1440);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Receiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, i, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * d, pendingIntent);
}
}
```

**RECEIVER**

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());

    long[] vibrate = {100, 100, 200, 300};
    notification.vibrate = vibrate;
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
}
```

Comment: Compare your both times. When you open the app that time and your fixed time and compare both . If its equals then send a notification.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I want that notifications are sent automatically although not open this app. does this make your solution?

Comment: But before that you have to check while your app is in foreground. And your code is in on onCreate() method and your receiver is called every time whenever you open app or back to this activity.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Could you help me by placing the correct code in a response?

Answer (score 0):

> Code to call CallThisClass.class every `int d` mins

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CallThisClass.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int d = Integer.valueOf(duration);
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 2);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * d, pendingIntent);
```

> Code to stop calling CallThisClass.class

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CallThisClass.class);
PendingIntent  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent, 0);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

> CallThisClass.class

```
public class CallThisClass extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Received", "Broadcast Received !");
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

> Dont forget Receiver inyour AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".CallThisClass" />
```

> And Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
```

You can start calling CallThisClass.class whenever you want. Eg. on a click of a button, or when your main activity start. Just make sure to Stop Calling the class when you dont want it working. Eg You want when the user first installs your application you want every 24 hours there should be something updated (notification or something), rit? in your prefrences store a variable that changes itself only if it is loaded for the first time. Check for that variable every time user enters application. if it is first time Start the Calling code. (now we dont want to call the stop code yet because we cant to keep on calling that class even if the application is closed!) close the application and it will work. And you can have a button in you setting or something for testing that when clicked will run code for not calling the class. It will stop the calling calling class every d mins i.e 24 hours in your case (also you can change the prefrnce to default value on clik of this button so that next time you start activity or click activate or something again that code to start calling that class starts). I hope it helps.

> Also, i would suggest a read [here for Best practices](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: This code goes in the onCreate of the Main? And ONLY repeated every d minutes?

Comment: I have edited my code with your code. But I have the same problem. The notification is always send